# Should we use absolute paths or relative paths for file names in configuration files?

Tags: linux, configuration-files, autoconf

I'm writing a set of programs in c++ which i want to be deployed across many machines and distributed to other developers for testing. How do I specify file paths in configuration files and how do I specify the location of the config files in cron jobs, command line, sample api etc?

I mean, should I use ROOT_DIR for my application and always specify file paths relative to this directory? What is the standard practice?

Can I use autoconf's configure script to write the ROOT_DIR in my application configuration files or should I stat the configuration file to find its location in the machine? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Autoconf, I believe you typically use the `--prefix` option to install an application to a non-default location. The default is system-wide.

Here is some [Autoconf documentation](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/Default-Prefix.html).

That way, users can decide if they want it system-wide or user-specific (or something else).

You may want to use the package manager that your OS provides. For instance, on Debian you might want to make a `deb` packages - other systems uses different package managers by default. This will help with resolving dependencies of your application(s).

E.g: If your application requires version X.Y of library Foo, the package manager can make sure your users have that before installing your package.

You could also look into [RPM Package Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager), which has been around for a while.

In short: there is no one answer. Common trope in Linux (:

Comment: i'm using autoconf --prefix option to let people install where they like. but not sure if I should let autoconf write this location's absolute path in program configuration files. currently distributing the application as tar.gz. will consider making it into a package. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
What is the standard practice?
```

You might want to check out the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) to clarify your thoughts of where things should be installed. It sounds like you probably want to be installing something in `/var/lib` instead of HOME_DIR, but it's hard to tell without more details.

Comment: thanks for the link. sorry for the poor wording though. i meant ROOT_DIR for my application. have edited the question. i expect people to install the application in /opt/ or a directory of their choice.